# php code not working correctly?

Tags: php

At

```
"$query = ("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());"
```

If I don't add `accounts`, `id` then `"$_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];"` wont work but if I do add it then login wont work also `accounts` is the database and `id` is inside of it.

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['users']) != ""){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">','index();','</script>';
}

require '../php/dbConnect.php';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
    $response = mysql_query($query);

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($response);

    if($row['password'] == md5($password))
    {
      $_SESSION['online'] = true;
      $_SESSION['users'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">','redirect();','</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo("Wrong Credentials");
 }
?>


<div id="friend-request-title" class="overlay round-edge panel-left">
 <label class="w3-text-white "><h2><b>Friend Requests</b></h2></label>
</div>
<div id="friend-request-panel" class="overlay round-edge panel-up">
 <?php
 require 'php/dbConnect.php';
     $query = ("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` <> '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
     $response = mysql_query($query);

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($response)) {
       echo '
       <div class="lesson-section">
       <div class="container">
        <img id="profile-image" src="img/profile2.png" class="big-circle float" style="margin: 4% 0 0 0;">
       </div>
       <label id="" class="w3-text-white"><h4><b>You have a new friend request.</b></h4></label>
       <label id="" class="w3-text-white">Friend request from '. $row['username'] .'.</label>
       <br>
       <button id="" class="w3-btn w3-text-white light-overlay border-remove round-edge" style="margin: 2% 2% 0 0;" type="button"><b>Accept</b></button>
       <button id="" class="w3-btn w3-text-white light-overlay border-remove round-edge" style="margin: 2% 0 0 0;" type="button"><b>Decline</b></button>
      </div>
      <hr>
       ';
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Md5. Really now?

Comment: sorry im a noob ~

Comment: dont use the mysql driver. use mysqli.  Im not sure where to start on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in this part of your php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['users']) != ""){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">','index();','</script>';
}
```

You should use isset then check if not empty

```
if(isset($_SESSION['users']) && $_SESSION['users'] != ""){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">','index();','</script>';
}
```

Comment: Why not `echo '<script type="text/javascript">index();</script>';`?